# Door counting application (filtering data MongoDB)

Tags: arrays, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

Right now i try to develop an simple application that is detect an people enter of the door using an radar device. After working with this i am able to store the data into the MongoDB database which have an schema like this `

```
tid: {
    type: String
},
xAxis: {
    type: String
},
yAxis: {
    type: String
}'
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlAe7.png)

In here: (take an example at first line in the database)

tid [0,1] is an target id and 0 and 1 represent for id of person 1 and 2 respectively.

xAxis [0.9043484,0.034612574] is an X coordinate of the target, which **0.9043484** is an x-coordinate of target **0** and **0.034612574** is an x-coordinate of target **1**

yAxis [0.6190742,0.60346264] is an Y coordinate of the target, which **0.6190742** is an y-coordinate of target **0** and **0.60346264** is an x-coordinate of target **1**

so we have two target is target '0' with have coordinate (0.9043484,0.6190742) and '1' is (0.034612574,0.60346264)

The idea of this application is i want to declare a line that when the target crossing that line it will count. (example when target have y-coordinate=2.42133 which is above line=2 it will count)

so now i want to check the yAxis database of each target to decide which one is crossing the line=2. There is an problem that because the data is insert to the database frequently so i dont know how to tracking the yAxis of that target to the time it cross the line.

so i hope somebody can help me,

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: are these coordinates referring to a particular item/user/component, or they are all unique ?

Comment: Hi, Don. These two xy-coordinate is belong to the position of the target that inside the range of the Radar and tid is an id of that target.